# the child is printing a wrong parent id (c program) the program is supposed to print the same process id as the first print statement?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, unistd.h, multiprogramming

It gives me the parent process as 707 always!
Should it it be giving the pid1 id?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid1 = getpid();
    printf("the parent id is %d \n", pid1);

    if (pid1 % 2 != 0) {
        printf("the parent id is odd\n");

    } else {
        printf("%d\n", getpid());
        printf("its even two childs were created\n");
        int i = fork();

        if (i == 0) {
            printf("child 1 chiled id is %d, parent is %d\n", getpid(),
                   getppid());

        } else {
            int i2 = fork();
            if (i2 == 0) {
                printf("child 2 chiled id is %d, parent is %d\n", getpid(),
                       getppid());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
the parent id is 6560 
6560
its even two childs were created
child 2 chiled id is 6562, parent is 707
child 1 chiled id is 6561, parent is 707
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parent process does not [*wait*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for its child processes, and is very likely to terminate before they have a chance to call `getppid`. When a parent process terminates before its children, the child processes become [orphan processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).

In Linux, orphan processes are either *reparented* to the `init` process (PID 1), or the nearest ancestor *subreaper* process, which performs the necessary task of *reaping* the child process  when it terminates. It would appear on your machine a subreaper is being employed, and that's the ID being returned by `getppid`.

(*See also [`prctl(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html), `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER` / `PR_GET_CHILD_SUBREAPER`*.)

(*The command `ps -p 707` would also give information about the process acting as the subreaper.*)

You need a construct like

```
while (wait(NULL) > 0)
    /* very basic example */;
```

at the bottom of the parent process to properly wait for and reap the child processes.